# GTA V PS4 with PC multiplayer compatibility

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, ps4

Is it possible to play GTA Online on PS4 with my friends on PC?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate but couldn't find the question so it may have been deleted? Anyway, answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no cross-platform play functionality in GTAV.